# How to use finite difference method to solve second order ODE with image eigenvalue?

Tags: numerical-methods

$-\phi'' +c(x) \phi(x) = f(x), \phi (0) = \alpha $ and $\phi (1) = \beta $
If we use central difference method to discretize $\phi ''$, we know when $c(x) \geq 0 $ the matrix is invertible. Thus, we can solve the linear algebra problem to find the numerical solution.

My question is: If $c(x)<0$ ?How can we solve this problem numerically if use the finite difference method?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and I just correct it. I mean if $c(x)<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear system to be solved reduces to
$$
\dfrac{-1}{2+h^2 c_i} \phi_{i+1} + \phi_i + \dfrac{-1}{2+h^2 c_i} \phi_{i-1} = \dfrac{h^2 f_i}{2+h^2 c_i}
$$

When $c_i > 0$, the matrix is diagonally dominant and thus invertible, as you already know. This can be extended easily for $c_i \ge 0$.

However, these conditions on $c(x)$ are only sufficient conditions, not necessary conditions, they do noy rule out the possibility of applying de FD method for more general $c(x)$.

I direct you to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959290273D) (Figure 1. is a must see). Based on their results, the condition
$$
(2+h^2c_i)(2+h^2 c_{i+1})\ge 4
$$
guarantees invertibility. But it is still a sufficient condition.